# error parsing XML mismatched tag Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development. I encounter this error while creating mail.xml. Below is the code and I have tried to look for solution on this website still giving the "error parsing XML mismatched tag Android". I will appreciate it if you can help check error in the code.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ScrollView android:layout_weight="30" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

     />

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

     </ScrollView>
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="40"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_content"
    android:text="Button" />
     </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="30"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

<AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     (This is at the beginjing of the code sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText tag isn't closed.
Change this

```
<EditText
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:ems="10" >
```

to this

```
<EditText
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: Thanks, i got this error when I fixed the Edit text tag..what might caused this?
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'fill_content'). mail.xml /Tes/res/layout line 99 Android AAPT Problem

Answer (score 0):

I found adding the closing tag like so: `</TextView>` keeps me from getting random errors like what you got there. With `</TextView>` I feel it looks more completed and I can see my code clearer. Either way works though.